# Practical limits on array size

Tags: javascript, arrays

Note: I'm really interested in "large" arrays sizes that work for other people. This is not the first time I've wondered about this and welcome feedback.

The scheme that I detail below requires development-effort towards that goal, so it's better to know going in whether I should eat the bandwidth and drop the idea, or whether this is a practical method for marginal gain on bandwidth. In other cases, for others who may be curious, or for future projects of mine, the gain may be larger.

Usually when I encounter a situation where a large javascript dataset is an option, there are usually other options and I tend to favor other options. I'm not actually sure what qualifies as large or too-large.

I'm wondering what safely works in production. I know that the theoretical limits but I can't find anything on the practical limits. As I detail below, my array is 14000 elemnts and 356k in size.

I realize, of course, that javascript is client side and depends on the specs of the client machine, my code, and to some extent, the version of the browser (in cases where related internal performance improved between versions).

Like any respectable modern website, it will have a mobile version as well and that's honestly where the memory concerns come in.

I don't actually think that this size is too large or near it for reasonable specs expectations of client machines, but I could be wrong and this is something I've long wondered about and haven't found any good information on. (Further, of course, the answer to this question would be quite different than it was *N* years ago).

Edit: I am aware of the 32-bit limitations on Array size, but I'm asking about what can work in healthy production and perform well.

---

#### Background:

I'm in the planning stages of a bible search engine.

I have a copy of the King James Version of the Bible filled with citations. Some of the citations are quite lengthy and as I'll be serving this over the net, I decided to rewrite the citations to an indexed array of the citations. That way I can rewrite the citations to shorter codes to shorter text and consume less bandwidth.

This leaves me with an array with 14,000 elements 356k in size, (216k of data) and the overall size of all the verses has shrunk by 20% (2mb, average of 65 bytes per verse). I would call this a gain.

A preview of the file looks like

```
['s=h07225','s=h0430','s=h0853','m=sm:th8804']
```

However, the potential downside is the memory consumed by using this array consistently with search results.

Comment: FWIW, arrays in JS cannot hold more than `2^32 - 2` values, because array indexes are 32bit numbers.

Comment: Yet, it turns out that 2^32 amounts to be 4.29 billion elements. Not exactly negligible.

Comment: Is there any reason to load all the citations into the client at once?

Comment: @FelixKling Thanks, but I'm trying to ask about practical limits in production. If I carry an array around with 4 billion elements, I might have some laggy pages :)

Comment: @KimGysen I'll use javascript to parse the bbml-esque citations and turn them into links (or hotsopots to pop up tooltips). So I need to be able to convert [c=1] to a link using data from array element 1.

Comment: @cfqueryparam I'm not sure I understand correctly. I'm sure there won't be a billion tooltips necessary in a single page? And what is `[c=1]`?

Comment: @KimGysen `[c=1]...[/c]` is a bbml-esque shortcode. I can use Javascript with regex to rewrite that to be something like `<A href="....s=h0430">...</a>`. You make a good point about not needing the whole array for result sets, but the alternative is regenerating that for each new search, which increases server-side time and decreases the value of cached javascripts.

Comment: @cfqueryparam how do you plan to use `"[c=1]"` to form an a tag? You could always use the often `String.prototype.link` method! after some parsing and whatnot, obv. :P

Comment: @RobG A small gain on bandwidth over-time.

Comment: @cfqueryparam Okay, I had no idea, interesting. I'm not sure what your app is doing really, but my take would be to retrieve results dynamically with ajax, paginate the results as RobG suggests, by sending dynamic query parameters over a REST interface. You can do some caching to easily get the most popular requested quotes. If there are so many quotes, what's the chance that users will read even 10 percent of them, and isn't it most interesting to show the X most popular every time? Perhaps I'm still misunderstanding the intent, this is just my two cents.

Comment: @cfqueryparam so check it: `var url = "http://example.com?"+"[a=3]".replace(/\[|\]/gi, ""); "link to scripture".link(URL);`

Comment: @FelixKling Why not 2^32 - 1?

Comment: @matcheek: I formulated it incorrectly. 2^32-2 is the highest index, so an array can have 2^32-1 elements.

Comment: @Todd Thanks for the tip on `.link()!

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation is to use `localStorage`, this way you can AJAX the data in so it doesn't impact initial page load. Once cached on the client, you are free to use it as you please. Also, you might need to add a way to keep checking for your array. You can check to see if it exists, and AJAX it in again if it doesn't. Local storage can be removed by the browser at any point in time.

Another alternative is to put in a JavaScript web resource that gets cached in the browser. You use `<script>` tags to bring it in. This file will declare the global array in your application. There is an `async` attribute available to have it load asynchronously. The downside here is figuring out when your array becomes available.

Comment: I do appreciate the thoughts on local storage. As for the second option. I'm mainly curious about the size of the array and if that's an issue.

Comment: 14,000 is well below the 2^32 limit. Modern websites (this one included, for example) are about 1.5MB. The idea is to load your data asynchronously and _cache_ it. Once cached, you can just focus on the rest of the content. Your main concern should be HTTP payloads. All that to say, you should be just fine.